# Ler ficheiros numa directoria ordenados por data de criação

Tags: php, arquivo, require

Tenho o seguinte código para incluir todos os ficheiros PHP que encontro numa  directoria:

```php
if (is_dir(CONF_REL_PATH_BANANAS)) {
  foreach (glob(CONF_REL_PATH_BANANAS.'/*.php') as $file) {
    require_once($file);
  }
}
```

Ao enviar para lá os ficheiros, tive o cuidado de os criar pela ordem que queria que eles fossem carregados, mas o resultado é:

```php
array(7) {
  [0]=&gt;
  string(29) "caminho/para/bananas/campaign.php"
  [1]=&gt;
  string(29) "caminho/para/bananas/contacts.php"
  [2]=&gt;
  string(29) "caminho/para/bananas/homepage.php"    // este seria o primeiro
  [3]=&gt;
  string(32) "caminho/para/bananas/participate.php"
  [4]=&gt;
  string(29) "caminho/para/bananas/partners.php"
  [5]=&gt;
  string(28) "caminho/para/bananas/picking.php"
  [6]=&gt;
  string(28) "caminho/para/bananas/results.php"
}
```

Ou seja, os ficheiros estão a aparecer ordenados alfabeticamente.

## Solução conhecida

Se manipular o nome dos ficheiros, resolve-se o problema facilmente:

```php
array(7) {
  [0]=&gt;
  string(31) "caminho/para/bananas/1_homepage.php"
  [1]=&gt;
  string(31) "caminho/para/bananas/2_campaign.php"
  [2]=&gt;
  string(34) "caminho/para/bananas/3_participate.php"
  [3]=&gt;
  string(30) "caminho/para/bananas/4_picking.php"
  [4]=&gt;
  string(31) "caminho/para/bananas/5_partners.php"
  [5]=&gt;
  string(30) "caminho/para/bananas/6_results.php"
  [6]=&gt;
  string(31) "caminho/para/bananas/7_contacts.php"
}
```

Mas isto levanta problemas de manutenção e adições futuras de novos ficheiros.

## Pergunta

Como posso ler os ficheiros existentes numa directoria obtendo os mesmos ordenados pela sua data de criação ?

Comment: Eu estive preparando toda uma resposta, mas dai percebi que a sua pergunta pedia ordenação pela *data de criação*. Descupe. :) Bom, ainda tentando ajudar, essa pergunta no SO em inglês talvez seja útil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Você não irá conseguir fazendo uso da funcao `scandir()` diretamente, mas dessa forma:

```php
$arquivos = glob('/pasta/*');
usort($arquivos, function($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});


//print_r($arquivos);
```